# iphone game caf sound effects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Caf file for sound effects. But some times some of the files just have no volume. Is it common for caf? After restarting, it's fine again. Instrument shows I've only a couple ofk's of memory leaks. I use soundbooth to edit and save wav as aiff then rename to caf

Comment: Are you using the simulator or the device for the testing? The simulator can sometimes be a bit buggy when it comes to sound.

Comment: simulator is fine. the device.

Comment: why you renamed it to caf?why can't you use aiff format itself!!

Comment: have you tried to clean the project and rebuild?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caf is an uncompressed format developed by Apple. Try using mp3 files, they are accepted by iphone, they weight less and work better in general.